# UNC sharing error in windows

Tags: asp.net, windows, operating-system

We five people working on the same project.
So we have share the project folder.
But when we debug the project from the different machines we get the error..
UNC sharing..

**ERROR**
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start monitoring changes to '\192.168.1.15\JSchoolSol\JSchool\teacher' because the network BIOS command limit has been reached. For more information on this error, please refer to Microsoft knowledge base article 810886. Hosting on a UNC share is not supported for the Windows XP Platform.

Answer (score 0):

**On the clients accessing the UNC share**

Registry edits:

1. DWORD `MaxCmds` at HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanworkstation\Parameters change/add with value > 50, max of 65535 - 8192 should be ok for workstations.
2. DWORD `MaxMpxCt` at HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters change/add with value > 50, max of 65535 - generally you'll want to configure this to be the same as MaxCmds.

**On the machine providing the network share**

Registry edits:

1. DWORD `MaxWorkItems` at HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters change/add with value > 4096, max 65535 - this is most easily calculated by Num_Clients * MaxCmds value on Clients -- or just max at 65535 if clients*clientsMaxCmdsValue is > 65535.
2. DWORD `MaxMpxCt` at HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters change/add with value > 50, max 65535 - I was under the impression that this is negotiated between the client and the server which the lower value of the two is what is applied. We tried various values up to max. In your case I would set this to 8192.

If you run into problems after this, you may want to consider FCNMode changes as well as possibly upgrading to a newer version of Windows for your file server to support newer versions of SMB (which seem to remedy this problem). For more details, please see my answer on a related topic [here (more geared toward hosting).](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20710473/705198)